Need advice on which Linear Algebra book to buy
I'm planning to buy a Linear Algebra book for both studying and as a reference. Here's my background and what I'm considering:

I took a Linear Algebra course during my undergraduate studies, so I'm not a complete beginner.
I'm looking for a solid reference book that I can use to refresh my knowledge and study further.
The books I'm considering are:

Linear Algebra by Stephen H. Friedberg
Linear Algebra and Its Applications by Gilbert Strang
Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler



I noticed that Axler's book has fewer pages than the others. Does it still cover the same topics as the other books? Also, if there are any other good recommendations for a Linear Algebra reference book, I'd really appreciate it!
Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Given your background and for what you want, perhaps Linear Algebra by Serge Lang. It is reasonably comprehensive for a "2nd level text" (see discussion here) and the exposition is crisp and appropriate (hence easy to dip in and read about something without getting lots of tangential issues). But compare it to Strang's book to see if the absence of some of the applications in Strang matter to you. Off-hand I don't know about Friedberg, but Axler is probably too distinctly individual for your purposes.
